# Cloudflare stops javascript passing variables to external files

Tags: javascript, php, cloudflare

I have Rocketloader enabled in my cloudflare account so that might be the issue, but how can I work around it?

The situation is I have an external file `login.js` which handles login forms across the site, but when a user accesses a page when they aren't logged in, the requested url is appended to the login page. An example of accessing `foo.com/secure/page26` when not logged in results in being directed to `foo.com/login.php?back=secure/page26`. so within my login page I have the following setup:

```
<script>var BackURL="secure/page26";</script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
```

Within `login.js` I have:

```
** SUCCESFULLY LOGGED IN SCRIPT HERE **
window.location.href = "/"+BackURL;
```

But this doesn't work, I guess it is due to Rocketloader, but how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the BackUrl parameter in a cookie and check for that cookie existence everytime you log in. If it's defined, then remove it and redirect the user to its value.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the excessive use of cookies (i.e. only store a session cookie for logged in users) in this project, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Whatever approach you take, your current cloudflare caching policy is aggresive enough to dismiss the query string. Perhaps you could try lowering the caching policy to the next step.

Comment: I'm testing the site on the direct subdomain, bypasing cloudflare entirely, and that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

"But this doesn't work, I guess it is due to Rocketloader, but how can I get around this?"

The easy way to check this would be to simply disable Rocket Loader in your settings & then try it again (might need to flush your browser cache after doing it). You could also pause CloudFlare entirely in your settings to see if the behavior changes).